# Germany Patent attorney fee

Tags: patent-applications, patent-services, attorney

Hi I am in contact with some Germany Attorney for a very simple furniture patent application. I attached a picture, and my patent is not complicated than this one. pls note I am applying for **patent**, not utility patent in German, which seems like a design patent in some country.

the quote is a little big from different attorney, I am sure they are patent attorney, just a little confused with the quotes, anyone has experience, and could give an price range in USD,

is it safer that I submit my application myself then I hire an attorney follow-up, I agree that will make the application complicated, in addition, should I pay all the fees once, or I can pay depending on the processing stage. thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure a patent even is applicable? Based on this site, I'd suggest registered design might be, but I don't see what the inventive step is in your stool. https://www.dpma.de/english/services/ip_rights_briefly_explained/index.html also https://www.dpma.de/english/designs/design_protection/index.html

Comment: it's not my concern about novelty and innovative, the picture is for ref, I just want to know how much the attorney fee is? I also don't need attorney to do prior art examination and research, just draft and submit, I have drawings and claims already but I think attorney need amend it in patentable terms , did I make myself clear?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am US based and can’t advise what German attorney fees are reasonable.